# Stored Procedure collation_connection is utf8mb4_general_ci instead of utf8mb4_unicode_ci using Hiedisql mysql

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

I am using Hiedisql V9.2.

I set default server `character-set is utfmb4` and `collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci` but after create stored procedure still show `collation_connection =utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Below is server my.ini settings.

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
init_connect                   = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character_set_%' OR
>   Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

After create stored procedure still show `collation_connection=utf8mb4_general_ci`.

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS where name LIKE 'ProcName'

+----------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Name     | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+----------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| ProcName | utf8mb4              | utf8mb4_general_ci   | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

So, how to fix `collation_connection=utf8mb4_general_ci` issue.

I want `collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got issue.
It is issue of Hiedisql tool which I am using. Hiedisql tool set `collation_connection=utf8mb4_general_ci` before run script.

**How to fix:**

Just set below variable value before run any script.

```
SET collation_connection = @@collation_database;
```

OR

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

Note: If you want to know what is actual collation, use `mysql command prompt` it will return actual result.

Comment: Tested with Toad for MySQL, same problems

Comment: pls try Hiedisql  latest version